# 'rel=external' is not working trying to link to external site

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I link to an external site in jQuery from a button within the header bar ?

I have tried below but it is not working.

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h4>Header</h4>
        <a rel='external' data-ajax="false" href='www.google.com' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l'>Google</a>
</div>
```

Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/1461/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefixing `http://` to the href would fix the issue.

```
<a data-rel='external' data-ajax="false" href='http://www.google.com' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l'>Google</a>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/1464/

Answer (score 1):

You need `data-rel="external"`, not `rel="external"`

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html

Comment: @user470184 Yes, the problem is a combination of this and the missing `http://` as mentioned by the marked answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-ajax="false"` on the link.

For example: `<a href="http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html" data-ajax="false">link</a>`