# issue with navigation using php and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using php and jquery mobile (newest releases) and having some problems with the navigation.

I have a page called index.php:

```
<a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a>
```

When the link is clicked it redirects to logout.php. The logout.php page looks like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);   
    if(session_destroy()) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

What happens is the URL in the browser changes to logout.php and shows a blank page. It does not go to the login.php page. If I refresh the page sing the refresh button on the browser it will redirect to login.php.

Googling the issue I found out it could be a problem with the php header call so I tried using javascript instead with no luck:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);   
    if(session_destroy()) {
        //header("Location: index.php");
        ?>
            <script>window.location.replace("index.php");</script>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: maybe this will help you : ['rel=external' is not working trying to link to external site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886945/rel-external-is-not-working-trying-to-link-to-external-site)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);   
header("Location: login.php");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this and the same result occurs.

Comment: I have tried the update answer with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `data-ajax="false"` to the log out link this way:

```
<a href="logout.php" data-ajax="false">Sign Out</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read this previously in another question, but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. it is the condition of check `!isset`. I have changed isset to empty and now it works.